# Comparing if obseration sets come from the same HMM

Tags: time-series, hidden-markov-model

I am using a recurrent network to try and "play" stock data. I want to ask the statistical question "is my model behaving randomly?"

I have two Markov chains. Both have 3 states buy, sell, hold. The first Markov chain is has the transitions controlled by my RNN. The second Markov chain just has equal probability of moving to all three states at any given time. Both chains are hidden by the same market. I only observe the daily returns. I therefore have two time series, each representing the daily returns from either chain.

Essentially, I want to know how to use these time series to test if the underlying Markov chains are significantly different. I am open to interpretation about what it means for the chain to be different.

I have not found a nice statistical test for this online so maybe you have some suggestions? Or maybe you think is a better way to ask this question?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "obfuscate the state with market performance."  I cannot make sense of this usage of "obfuscate."  Then could you explain more precisely what you mean by chains to be "significantly different"?  What aspects of these chains are you trying to compare?

Comment: I am saying that the hidden part of this HMM is how the market's movement hides what state the chain is in. One day I see a negative return, but I do not know if that is because the portfolio is in a long position and the stock went down or because the portfolio is in a short position and the stock went up. The portfolio's position is the sum of the visited states.